# What to use to iterate until "n"

Tags: python, iteration

```
def divisor(n):   
        t=[]   
        i=range(1,n+1)   #int object is not iterable
        for i in n:
            if i%n==0:
                return t.append(i)
```

*The task is to give out every factor of a given number n in a list. I tried it with range but since range is not iterable i cant use it. So my question is what could i use to iterate from 1 until n ?I did not find anything so i wanted to try to ask here, i am thankful for any advice on how to fix this problem.*

Comment: `for i in range(1,n+1):`

Comment: You are iterating over the argument to the function, not your created range. Ranges are iterable. You should also be careful not to alias the same `i` variable twice

Comment: " but since range is not iterable i cant use it" .... uh, nope. `range` objects are iterable, that's their whole *raison d'etre*. `int` objects, on the other hand, are not...

Comment: So if i say "if range(1,n+1)%n==0" the problem would be the n? if i can't use range and int what would i use otherwise for this. Sorry i am kinda new to python/programming and still do alot of mistakes....

Comment: If `n` is a number, you will get and error since integers are not iterable.  You are safe using `for i in range(1,n+1):` as @CoryKramer suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in xrange(1, n)
```

xrange is efficient than `range`

Comment: This is only true in python 2.

Comment: Agreed. But python version was not in question. However, thanks for making it clear.

Comment: Then just use the normal `range`.  In Python 3, it does the same thing.